# Scraping Data for hidden HTML using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am currently working on a project to **scrape** financial data for stock in Yahoo Finance website. The process is straightforward to **scrape** yearly data but when it comes to quarterly I need to click on Quarterly and then get the HTML.

I will go through an example to explain:
When you go to this link: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/financials?p=MSFT , you can easily **scrape** the data with this code :

```html
my_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SQ/financials?p=SQ'

uclient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uclient.read()
#Close the client
uclient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs each container in the html page
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"data-test": "fin-row"})
```

But when it comes to getting quarterly data, I need to click on the `quaterly` button next to `yearly` to get the quarterly data.

For that, I am using selenium and wrote this code :

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(my_url)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Col1-1-Financials-Proxy']/section/div[1]/div[2]/button")
ActionChains(driver).click(element).perform()
```

I don't understand why this is not working and it is not able to click on the quarterly and get me the data I want.
Or maybe there is no need to use selenium to get this hidden HTML. Could you please help and advice on how to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you have wrong xpath, or it is inside `<iframe>` which may needs `driver.switch_to.frame(...)` BTW: there is module [yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance) to get some data from Yahoo Finance

Comment: what happend when you run Selenium ? Is this click it in browser? After click you have to use `driver.page_source` to get new HTML and use in `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 1):

When I try to click `Quarterly` it looks like it changes page but after that it changes it back to `Annual` - so I used `time.sleep(5)` and it has time to load `Annual` data before I click `Quarterly` and it display correct data.

BTW: At start I see window with information about my privacy and I have to click button `"Agree"`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

my_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SQ/financials?p=SQ'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(my_url)

# Agree Button
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="agree"]')
element.click()

time.sleep(5)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@data-reactid="20"]')
element.click()

#time.sleep(5)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

#grabs each container in the html page
containers = soup.find_all("div", {"data-test": "fin-row"})
for item in containers:
    print(item.text)
```

---

Page uses JavaScript to load `Quarterly` data and probably using this `url` you get it as `JSON` data - but there is so many data adn I don't know what you need.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/SQ?lang=en-US&region=US&symbol=SQ&padTimeSeries=true&type=quarterlyTaxEffectOfUnusualItems%2CtrailingTaxEffectOfUnusualItems%2CquarterlyTaxRateForCalcs%2CtrailingTaxRateForCalcs%2CquarterlyNormalizedEBITDA%2CtrailingNormalizedEBITDA%2CquarterlyNormalizedDilutedEPS%2CtrailingNormalizedDilutedEPS%2CquarterlyNormalizedBasicEPS%2CtrailingNormalizedBasicEPS%2CquarterlyTotalUnusualItems%2CtrailingTotalUnusualItems%2CquarterlyTotalUnusualItemsExcludingGoodwill%2CtrailingTotalUnusualItemsExcludingGoodwill%2CquarterlyNetIncomeFromContinuingOperationNetMinorityInterest%2CtrailingNetIncomeFromContinuingOperationNetMinorityInterest%2CquarterlyReconciledDepreciation%2CtrailingReconciledDepreciation%2CquarterlyReconciledCostOfRevenue%2CtrailingReconciledCostOfRevenue%2CquarterlyEBITDA%2CtrailingEBITDA%2CquarterlyEBIT%2CtrailingEBIT%2CquarterlyNetInterestIncome%2CtrailingNetInterestIncome%2CquarterlyInterestExpense%2CtrailingInterestExpense%2CquarterlyInterestIncome%2CtrailingInterestIncome%2CquarterlyContinuingAndDiscontinuedDilutedEPS%2CtrailingContinuingAndDiscontinuedDilutedEPS%2CquarterlyContinuingAndDiscontinuedBasicEPS%2CtrailingContinuingAndDiscontinuedBasicEPS%2CquarterlyNormalizedIncome%2CtrailingNormalizedIncome%2CquarterlyNetIncomeFromContinuingAndDiscontinuedOperation%2CtrailingNetIncomeFromContinuingAndDiscontinuedOperation%2CquarterlyTotalExpenses%2CtrailingTotalExpenses%2CquarterlyRentExpenseSupplemental%2CtrailingRentExpenseSupplemental%2CquarterlyReportedNormalizedDilutedEPS%2CtrailingReportedNormalizedDilutedEPS%2CquarterlyReportedNormalizedBasicEPS%2CtrailingReportedNormalizedBasicEPS%2CquarterlyTotalOperatingIncomeAsReported%2CtrailingTotalOperatingIncomeAsReported%2CquarterlyDividendPerShare%2CtrailingDividendPerShare%2CquarterlyDilutedAverageShares%2CtrailingDilutedAverageShares%2CquarterlyBasicAverageShares%2CtrailingBasicAverageShares%2CquarterlyDilutedEPS%2CtrailingDilutedEPS%2CquarterlyDilutedEPSOtherGainsLosses%2CtrailingDilutedEPSOtherGainsLosses%2CquarterlyTaxLossCarryforwardDilutedEPS%2CtrailingTaxLossCarryforwardDilutedEPS%2CquarterlyDilutedAccountingChange%2CtrailingDilutedAccountingChange%2CquarterlyDilutedExtraordinary%2CtrailingDilutedExtraordinary%2CquarterlyDilutedDiscontinuousOperations%2CtrailingDilutedDiscontinuousOperations%2CquarterlyDilutedContinuousOperations%2CtrailingDilutedContinuousOperations%2CquarterlyBasicEPS%2CtrailingBasicEPS%2CquarterlyBasicEPSOtherGainsLosses%2CtrailingBasicEPSOtherGainsLosses%2CquarterlyTaxLossCarryforwardBasicEPS%2CtrailingTaxLossCarryforwardBasicEPS%2CquarterlyBasicAccountingChange%2CtrailingBasicAccountingChange%2CquarterlyBasicExtraordinary%2CtrailingBasicExtraordinary%2CquarterlyBasicDiscontinuousOperations%2CtrailingBasicDiscontinuousOperations%2CquarterlyBasicContinuousOperations%2CtrailingBasicContinuousOperations%2CquarterlyDilutedNIAvailtoComStockholders%2CtrailingDilutedNIAvailtoComStockholders%2CquarterlyAverageDilutionEarnings%2CtrailingAverageDilutionEarnings%2CquarterlyNetIncomeCommonStockholders%2CtrailingNetIncomeCommonStockholders%2CquarterlyOtherunderPreferredStockDividend%2CtrailingOtherunderPreferredStockDividend%2CquarterlyPreferredStockDividends%2CtrailingPreferredStockDividends%2CquarterlyNetIncome%2CtrailingNetIncome%2CquarterlyMinorityInterests%2CtrailingMinorityInterests%2CquarterlyNetIncomeIncludingNoncontrollingInterests%2CtrailingNetIncomeIncludingNoncontrollingInterests%2CquarterlyNetIncomeFromTaxLossCarryforward%2CtrailingNetIncomeFromTaxLossCarryforward%2CquarterlyNetIncomeExtraordinary%2CtrailingNetIncomeExtraordinary%2CquarterlyNetIncomeDiscontinuousOperations%2CtrailingNetIncomeDiscontinuousOperations%2CquarterlyNetIncomeContinuousOperations%2CtrailingNetIncomeContinuousOperations%2CquarterlyEarningsFromEquityInterestNetOfTax%2CtrailingEarningsFromEquityInterestNetOfTax%2CquarterlyTaxProvision%2CtrailingTaxProvision%2CquarterlyPretaxIncome%2CtrailingPretaxIncome%2CquarterlyOtherIncomeExpense%2CtrailingOtherIncomeExpense%2CquarterlyOtherNonOperatingIncomeExpenses%2CtrailingOtherNonOperatingIncomeExpenses%2CquarterlySpecialIncomeCharges%2CtrailingSpecialIncomeCharges%2CquarterlyGainOnSaleOfPPE%2CtrailingGainOnSaleOfPPE%2CquarterlyGainOnSaleOfBusiness%2CtrailingGainOnSaleOfBusiness%2CquarterlyOtherSpecialCharges%2CtrailingOtherSpecialCharges%2CquarterlyWriteOff%2CtrailingWriteOff%2CquarterlyImpairmentOfCapitalAssets%2CtrailingImpairmentOfCapitalAssets%2CquarterlyRestructuringAndMergernAcquisition%2CtrailingRestructuringAndMergernAcquisition%2CquarterlySecuritiesAmortization%2CtrailingSecuritiesAmortization%2CquarterlyEarningsFromEquityInterest%2CtrailingEarningsFromEquityInterest%2CquarterlyGainOnSaleOfSecurity%2CtrailingGainOnSaleOfSecurity%2CquarterlyNetNonOperatingInterestIncomeExpense%2CtrailingNetNonOperatingInterestIncomeExpense%2CquarterlyTotalOtherFinanceCost%2CtrailingTotalOtherFinanceCost%2CquarterlyInterestExpenseNonOperating%2CtrailingInterestExpenseNonOperating%2CquarterlyInterestIncomeNonOperating%2CtrailingInterestIncomeNonOperating%2CquarterlyOperatingIncome%2CtrailingOperatingIncome%2CquarterlyOperatingExpense%2CtrailingOperatingExpense%2CquarterlyOtherOperatingExpenses%2CtrailingOtherOperatingExpenses%2CquarterlyOtherTaxes%2CtrailingOtherTaxes%2CquarterlyProvisionForDoubtfulAccounts%2CtrailingProvisionForDoubtfulAccounts%2CquarterlyDepreciationAmortizationDepletionIncomeStatement%2CtrailingDepreciationAmortizationDepletionIncomeStatement%2CquarterlyDepletionIncomeStatement%2CtrailingDepletionIncomeStatement%2CquarterlyDepreciationAndAmortizationInIncomeStatement%2CtrailingDepreciationAndAmortizationInIncomeStatement%2CquarterlyAmortization%2CtrailingAmortization%2CquarterlyAmortizationOfIntangiblesIncomeStatement%2CtrailingAmortizationOfIntangiblesIncomeStatement%2CquarterlyDepreciationIncomeStatement%2CtrailingDepreciationIncomeStatement%2CquarterlyResearchAndDevelopment%2CtrailingResearchAndDevelopment%2CquarterlySellingGeneralAndAdministration%2CtrailingSellingGeneralAndAdministration%2CquarterlySellingAndMarketingExpense%2CtrailingSellingAndMarketingExpense%2CquarterlyGeneralAndAdministrativeExpense%2CtrailingGeneralAndAdministrativeExpense%2CquarterlyOtherGandA%2CtrailingOtherGandA%2CquarterlyInsuranceAndClaims%2CtrailingInsuranceAndClaims%2CquarterlyRentAndLandingFees%2CtrailingRentAndLandingFees%2CquarterlySalariesAndWages%2CtrailingSalariesAndWages%2CquarterlyGrossProfit%2CtrailingGrossProfit%2CquarterlyCostOfRevenue%2CtrailingCostOfRevenue%2CquarterlyTotalRevenue%2CtrailingTotalRevenue%2CquarterlyExciseTaxes%2CtrailingExciseTaxes%2CquarterlyOperatingRevenue%2CtrailingOperatingRevenue&merge=false&period1=493590046&period2=1591768381&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com'

r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

---

**BTW:** There is module [yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance) which can gives many data but I don't know if it gives all what you need.

Here example based on example from documentation.

```
import yfinance as yf

data = yf.Ticker("SQ")

# get stock info
print(data.info)

# get historical market data
hist = data.history(period="max")
print(hist)

# show actions (dividends, splits)
print(data.actions)

# show dividends
print(data.dividends)

# show splits
print(data.splits)

# show financials
print(data.financials)
print(data.quarterly_financials)

# show major holders
print(data.major_holders)

# show institutional holders
print(data.institutional_holders)

# show balance heet
print(data.balance_sheet)
print(data.quarterly_balance_sheet)

# show cashflow
print(data.cashflow)
print(data.quarterly_cashflow)

# show earnings
print(data.earnings)
print(data.quarterly_earnings)

# show sustainability
print(data.sustainability)

# show analysts recommendations
print(data.recommendations)

# show next event (earnings, etc)
print(data.calendar)

# show ISIN code - *experimental*
# ISIN = International Securities Identification Number
print(data.isin)

# show options expirations
print(data.options)
```